# Why transistor is non-linear in Cutoff & Saturation mode?

Tags: transistors, bjt

I am imagining Linearity in the sense that

```
F(ax+by)=aF(x) + bF(y)
```

Now suppose I have BJT characteristic curve :
[image]

In Active region, The response is : Ic = F(Vce) = const. So it is <strike>linear.</strike>
In Cut off region, Response is : Ic = F(Vce) = 0.
- No matter how large the increase in Vce, Ic is still zero. It is Similar to Air gap. So it should be linear as well.
In Saturation region, Response is : Ic = const * Vce. With const being the slope of the curve. In reasonable Vce, I see this slope is of a straight line (not of a power function). So it is also linear in this region.

What was wrong in the above argument that I applied to BJT ?

Edit: Actually , function : y = b is non-linear **map**

Answer (score 1):

Those are linear approximations of the true behavior (many times quite accurate approximations).

The [Ebers-Moll model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Ebers.E2.80.93Moll_model) describes the behavior of BJT's more precisely:

[image: collector current]
[image: base current]
[image: emitter current]

Clearly non-linear behavior.