# Proportional control of 0-12 V DC power source with 0-5 V DC analog signal

Tags: transistors, analog, motor-controller, instrumentation

I am taking an instrumentation class and for our final project we are modeling a ventilated barn, to do this we want to vary the speed of a 12 V DC 0.35 Amp fan. To control the fan we are sending a 0-5 VDC analog signal from a DAC (1408 FS PLUS).

Everything that I have found is saying to use a manually controlled potentiometer, i.e variable resistance. But we would like to control the fan's speed with the analog signal since we can control that with our programming.

Our professor has been leading us towards using a power transistor and this seems like it could work for us but my question is when you send the control signal to the transistor is the output proportional to the input signal or do you need to send the full 5 V DC to the transistor to "enable" it.

In the lab we were using a 2N6346 NPN Transistor with a 133 Ohm resistor and it was "sort of" working but we aren't sure if the output is reliable. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

- Our professor wants us to use the basics to make it work, if it is possible

Comment: Regarding reliability, some fans won't start turning if you power it on the "low" setting (i.e. large voltage drop on transistor or low duty cycle), so you'd have to start at full or high speed for a few secs then slow it down. But I'm not sure if this is within the scope of the exercise..

Comment: What are you using as an input to tell you how to adjust the DAC output? Temperature? Time? Or what, exactly? In short, why do you care at all to adjust the fan speed? Is there a goal here? Or is this merely a demonstration about replacing a potentiometer? Also, is 12 V the only power source for the fan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a power transistor, but not on it's own.

You will need some form of control circuit to properly apply power to the motor in proportion to the ADC voltage.

Also, the linear method you are thinking about, basically a voltage regulator, is horribly inefficient at lower speeds. A pulse width modulated control system that turns the power full on and full off at different proportions at a high frequency, is a much better solution.

However, a very simple, one of, solution can be fashioned this way...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyhTdX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit actually adjusts the maximum current than will flow through the motor, and consequently the maximum torque available, which in turn limits how fast it can go. The POT needs to be sized based on the worst case \$\beta\$ of the selected transistor, and you would adjust it so that at max ADC value, you get maximum current through the MOTOR and the transistor is close to the saturation point. R1 is only there to protect your ADC in the event that you crank the POT all the way to the zero resistance end.

Speed control will NOT be linear with ADC value though since it will be dependent on the mechanical load, which for a fan, is not linear with speed. Also, to get the fan started, you would need to begin with a high torque setting then back off some time later.

Answer (score 2):

> but my question is when you send the control signal to the transistor is the output proportional to the input signal or do you need to send the full 5 V DC to the transistor to "enable" it.

If it is a BJT transistor, then the current you put in through the *base* will be amplified by some \$\beta\$. This \$\beta\$ is fairly constant during it's active region. [In its others regions, not so much](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66609/why-transistor-is-non-linear-in-cutoff-saturation-mode).

So in the way you will be using it, you would probably be in its active regions the way you're describing how you're going to use it. But putting a transistor instead of a potentiometer is just like moving the heatsink around. Instead of putting the heatsink on your potentiometer you're now putting it on the transistor, so part-wise it doesn't make much sense.

> Our professor is the kind who wants us to use the basics to make it work, if it is possible

He will most certainly then be OK if you connect the output of a DAC into a resistor and then into the base of an NPN transistor. It will solve your problem in the easiest way possible.

This is the [schematic](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+50%0At+672+336+704+336+0+1+-0.2477198451174515+0.7520882089411284+100%0Ar+560+336+672+336+0+1000%0Ar+704+192+704+240+0+10%0AR+704+192+704+128+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+704+352+704+368+0%0A172+560+336+528+336+0+6+5+5+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0Ax+553+248+677+251+4+24+Fan%5Csmodel%0Aw+704+288+704+320+0%0Ax+465+373+601+376+4+24+DAC%5Csoutput%0Al+704+240+704+288+0+0.0001+0.4247911791160141%0Ao+5+64+0+4099+5+0.00625+0+2+5+3%0Ao+2+64+0+4099+5+0.8+1+2+2+3%0A) I'm suggesting, basic stuff. Go ahead and change the DAC output voltage to simulate what you will be doing.

---

If this would have been more serious, like if you were making mass production of some item. Then you would have used a MOSFET and PWM, because the losses would have been a fraction of what you will be doing with your NPN transistor in active region.

The NPN transistor will be used as a variable resistor limiting the current to your fan, while using a MOSFET and a PWM you, loosely speaking, open / close the circuit which stops the current going to the fan, so the limiting part takes very low energy, compared to a limiting resistor. In theory it's lossless, in reality you have switching losses and \$R_{D(ON)}\$ and other parasitics.

Also you would have used a flyback diode in parallel with the fan (if you used a MOSFET with a PWM, you won't need it with your BJT in active region), sure the fan is low power, but the noise on the power line would be reduced.

This is the [schematic](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+5.000000000000001e-7+0.26073472713092677+47+5+50%0Af+608+288+656+288+0+1.5+2%0Ag+656+304+656+336+0%0Aa+448+288+544+288+0+5+0+1000000+3.7499999999904254+3.3%0AR+448+272+416+272+0+4+100000+2.5+2.5+0+0.5%0A172+448+304+400+304+0+6+3.3+5+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0Ax+466+179+590+182+4+24+Fan%5Csmodel%0Al+656+176+656+224+0+0.0001+0.3036511944856245%0Ar+656+128+656+176+0+10%0AR+656+128+656+64+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+656+224+656+272+0%0Ad+624+224+624+128+1+0.805904783%0Aw+656+224+624+224+0%0Aw+624+128+656+128+0%0Aw+544+288+608+288+0%0Ax+432+372+618+375+4+24+PWM%5Csgenerator%0Ao+4+8+0+4099+5+0.00009765625+0+2+4+3%0Ao+7+1+0+4099+6.507702728223379+0.49300778244116505+1+2+7+3%0A) I'm talking about, less basic. Though not most advanced.

You can also use a BJT transistor with PWM, but that's not *basic* in my opinion, and probably not in your professors eyes either. But it would be more efficient than using it as a passive resistor which you will be doing, which is basic.